# How can I pass babel options through class options?

Tags: babel, class-options

I built a class upon the article class. This class load a package where the `\maketitle` command is define. If I do not load babel inside the class, the title of the document is always in english (the date). Thus, I would like to pass the language in the class options, but I also would like to keep the possibility to load article class options. How can I do ?

I would like to do something like:

```
\documentclass[language, opt1, opt2]{myclass}
```

where in myclass, I send `language` to babel and `opt1, opt2` to the article class. This is the beginnig of my class :

```
% default options
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

% load base class
\LoadClass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Giving the option globally can be a handy thing. The class file
passes the options further to packages. You mentioned the
language, let's have a look at it.

Internally, `siunitx` loads package `translator` (part of the
beamer bundle). `translator` can *see* the global option for the
language and react by using the right dictionary.

Another famous instance where a global option is passed to a
package is `draft`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.cls}
\ProvidesClass{\jobname}[2014/10/15 test class TeX.SX]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\begin{center}
\Huge \@date
\end{center}
}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[
draft,
%draft=true,
%ngerman
french
]{\jobname}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mwe}%loads graphicx
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Let the pizza dough leaven for \SIrange{18}{24}{\hour}. Is the
draft option working here? hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{document}
```

**Off-topic general advice**
Are there any tripwires? Of course. Designing a new class is
a delicate thing. The standard classes come with some basic
options. The KOMA classes (a featureful enhancement of the
standard bundle) come with a whole load of options to make almost
any design change.   Neither the standard nor KOMA classes do care
of any *locale*s (except letter vs DIN paper). The user is in
charge.

An alternative to `babel` is `polyglossia`. Both do the same
thing, but polyglossia has another syntax. So giving `ngerman`
(or `french`) as a global option isn't known by polyglossia and
hence ignored. Using the polyglossia syntax, `translator` won't
know the option and hence ignore it.

You can catch some of the stuff, and take care of it, but it is
impossible to take every little instance of user behaviour into
account.

I once saw a custom class taking options via a key-value-syntax.
Please replace `draft` by `draft=true` in the above example and
take a look at the output. Package `graphicx` doesn't know the
syntax and thus ignores it.

Comment: Yes it works! But what is the trick ? How Latex know that the french or ngerman option of the class have to be pass to babel and not another package ?

Comment: If `amsmath` gets the option french or ngerman, it will just ignore it. `siunitx` will pick it up as well. Some new features of babel won't work with global options and need to be given as a package option directly.